# javax.persistence.PersistenceException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Tags: java, jpa, cliente-servidor, permissões, rmi

Criei um arquivo policy que dá a permissão para a minha máquina executar tanto o cliente quanto o servidor, também passei as portas para os mesmos. Dentro do servidor eu instancio o RMI Security (já que se eu tirar ele o policy não funciona)

Servidor iniciado funciona ok. Cliente começa a funcionar ok. Termino de inserir o último campo para criar um novo usuário no banco de dados e vem esses erros.

Cliente:

> java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return; nested
>   exception is:     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException (no security manager: RMI class
>   loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:247)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)    at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
>     at
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.inserir(Unknown Source)    at
>   rmi.cliente.Servicos.adicionarUsuario(Servicos.java:42)   at
>   rmi.cliente.RMICliente.main(RMICliente.java:16) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException (no security manager: RMI class
>   loader disabled)  at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:396)    at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:186)    at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
>     at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:214)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:245)
>     ... 6 more

Obs: O servidor parou de dar erro, agora é só o cliente.

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema parece ser classpath, pois observe isso daqui:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)     at
>   rmi.cliente.Servicos.adicionarUsuario(Servicos.java:42)

Ou seja, na sua classe `Servicos` que está do lado do cliente, houve uma tentativa de se acessar a classe `PersistenceException`. Esta classe provavelmente não existe do lado do cliente, pois não deve fazer sentido ter o JAR do JPA do lado do cliente.

Ocorre que quando a `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` é serializada do servidor para o cliente, o cliente não consegue desserializar, pois a exceção não existe lá. O resultado é um erro na desserialização.

Então o que está acontecendo é o seguinte:

1. Ocorreu um erro na persistência do servidor.
2. O erro foi serializado e enviado para o cliente.
3. O cliente não conseguiu desserializar a exceção e isso ocasionou uma outra exceção.

E você talvez consiga ver a `PersistenceException` no lado do servidor com todas as informações que fizeram ela ser lançada.

Para corrigir isso, eis algumas possibilidades:

- Acrescentar o JAR do JPA no classpath do cliente.
- Acrescentar a classe `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` isoladamente no classpath do cliente.
- Do lado do servidor, não deixar a `PersistenceException` ser serializada para o cliente nunca. Para fazer isso, utilize os blocos `try...catch` de uma forma que evitem isso. É importante atestar-se que a `PersistenceException` não vaze nem mesmo como sendo a causa de uma exceção de nível mais alto.

Comment: Victor, eu coloquei o JAR, e então o erro mudou! Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named ServidorPU
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)

Comment: @Joana Esse provavelmente é o erro que aconteceu no servidor. Este erro está dizendo que o arquivo `persistence.xml` não foi encontrado do lado do servidor com uma persistence-unit chamada ServidorPU.

Comment: "Acrescentar a classe javax.persistence.PersistenceException isoladamente no classpath do cliente." como eu faço isso?

Comment: Pois é, só que ele está no código do servidor... rs

Comment: @Joana, neste último, crie um JAR com apenas esta classe. Entretanto, não garanto que isso funcione. E só vai funcionar se a primeira alternativa também funcionar (mas o contrário não necessariamente é verdadeiro).

Comment: @Joana, talvez o `persistence.xml` esteja na pasta errada.

Comment: Estranho é que quando eu dou grant all no policy tudo funciona =( haha

Comment: @Joana Então provavelmente este é o erro do servidor. Havia dois erros, um no servidor e um no cliente. O erro do servidor é esse policy. O erro no cliente era o problema da serialização da `PersistenceException`.